# How can I create a cloud function 2nd gen which will be triggered when new entry comes to a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to create a function which will be triggered when new entry was inserted into a BigQuery table called "staging_tbl".

```
staging_tbl
A    | B    | C
val1 | val2 | val3
```

Often new entries will be inserted and I want that everytime when a new entry is inserted into the table, a cloud function is triggered with this entry.

I have a function with the following trigger:

```
  event_trigger = {
    trigger_region        = var.region
    event_type            = "google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished"
    pubsub_topic          = "projects/${var.project_id}/topics/greeny_data_inserted_in_tbl"
    retry_policy          = "RETRY_POLICY_DO_NOT_RETRY"
    service_account_email = var.tf_service_account
  }
```

How should I create the subscription?

Comment: What's your database engine?

Comment: Oh, its BigQuery.

Comment: There is no event when a single row is inserted in BigQuery. You can listen the logs to detect the insert, update, delete logs, but also the stream and the load jobs. It's a complex task today and you should try to do differently. Add an insert date (default column) and perform a request every minute to get the latest row?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki. As what guillaume blaquiere said, you can opt instead to add an insert date column and perform a request every minute to get the latest row. You can write a script in cloud function and use scheduler to schedule pulling latest data from big query and writing it to another table.